# Printing state of wiringpi pin onto webpage

Tags: php, wiringpi, javascript, html5

I have a Pi set up with Apache and wiringpi, and I would like to read the state of an `in` pin (every 20 seconds, if possible) and display it on my webpage using PHP. The input is to determine if my computer is on or off remotely.

So basically, I want to store the output of a `system(gpio -g read 7)` command into a variable (`$status`) and then print it on the page like so:

`Your computer is currently: $status.`

Where $status can be either `on` or `off` depending on if the `read` command comes back as a `1` or `0`.

I can post what code I already have, but right now it just sends a power toggle out of a GPIO `out` pin.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: I'd suggest that your web page makes a REST call back to a back-end application running on the Pi.  For example a node.js/express app.  This could then inquire the data values you want and return it as a JSON encoded set of data.  Your web page could then interrogate that data and dynamically update the page without any page reloads.  I don't know of any pre-canned code to do that but the complexity doesn't sound high if one can program web pages, Node.js and the wiring-pi npm library.

Answer (score 1):

If one googles this phrase "raspberry pi gpio web interface" and switches to images mode, we can see that there appear to be quite a number of pre-existing solutions and samples.  For example:

http://hackaday.com/2013/02/02/easy-web-interface-with-gpio-access-runs-on-raspberry-pi/

https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=15257

http://www.cupidcontrols.com/2014/04/raspberry-pi-cupid-webio-javascriptjquery-apache-python/

and quite a few others.